# Configure SSL certificate on Server 2012

Tags: ssl, certificate, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install the SSL certificate on my server 2012. The steps I followed are:
1. I created a CSR certificate by going to IIS- Server certificate- create a certificate request. I filled out the form of common name, organization city etc. and I saved the information for the certificate as a text file (.txt) and I tried also saving as .p7b. When I go again to IIS- server certificates- complete certificate request, and then "File name containing the certification authority's response" I click the ... but it doesn't recognize the text file I saved from the CSR step as a certificate. Any idea how can I convert it as a certificate? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should update your operating system. Server 2012 mainstream support ended on [10/9/2018](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=windows%20server%202012).
2. You created a **Certificate Signing Request** (CSR) not a certificate. Now you need someone to sign it. Depending on your requirements in terms of **trust** you may:

   - Submit the certificate request to a public CA (or use [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) but most ACME client applications produce the CSR themselves).
   - Build your own (real) Certificate Authority to sign your certificate - a non trivial task to set up and keep running!
   - Self sign your request with tolls like [OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority) or [PowerShell](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/153255-windows-10-signing-a-powershell-script-with-a-self-signed-certificate) (create self signed but not from CSR), [MakeCert](https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/) (create self signed but not from CSR).